# Фильтр по дате не работает

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос

Подскажите, пожалуйста, не могу понять в чем проблема. Есть запрос:

```
select ID
   , PhoneNum
   , DateCall
   , CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ss, (Duration), 0), 108) as "Duration"    
from Calls 
where 
    DateCall > '2022-04-01 00:00:00' 
    and DateCall < '2022-05-01 00:00:00' 
    and len(PhoneNum) = 12 
    and PhoneNum like '9811%' 
    or PhoneNum like '9822%' 
    or PhoneNum like '9833%'
```

Если я делаю запрос в таком формате, то у меня идет выборка по всем датам, а не только по выбранной в запросе. Если `like` убрать, то выборка по дате работает корректно.

Comment: потому что условия перечисленные через or надо в скобки завернуть

Comment: Нашёл подобный вопрос по выборке данных между 2 данными. Пробовали сделать так же? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945722/selecting-between-two-dates-within-a-datetime-field-sql-server. К тому же, у вас не хватает скобок. Может быть в этом дело?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ваши условия сейчас равносильны `(x & y & a) || b || c` а надо вам `x & y & (a || b || c)`

```
AND (
 phonenum like ...
 OR phonenum like ...
 OR phonenum like ...
)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что надо.

Comment: @Михаил галку ткните вопросу тогда.